# How could I get rid of the Laser Targeting System on my Sniper Rifle?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I unfortunately installed a [Laser Targeting System](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_mods_%28DX3%29#Laser_Targeting_System) to my [Silenced sniper rifle](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Silenced_sniper_rifle) and never used the rifle for several hours. When I needed it, I discovered it was now unreliable, as it's mentioned on [Sniper Rifle wikia article](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper_rifle_%28DX3%29#Upgrades).

Now, If I want to get rid of it, what should I do? Also note that I have put others upgrades into it that I would like to keep and, as I said, I played several hours before notifying the problem so loading the save game is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove upgrades from a weapon. You could sell it and buy back an unupgraded version, or find a new one. In short, you will have to reload or lose the upgrades.